# How to run wsgi and usual site on one apache server?

Tags: apache, centos7, mod-wsgi

I have an apache server on VPS powered by centos7.

I have a usual website here, and now I want to add flask application.

- **httpme.tk** is my flask application
- **mniek.ru** is my website

so, the configs looks like that:

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/http_error_api.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName www.httpme.tk
    ServerAlias httpme.tk
    WSGIDaemonProcess application user=apache group=apache threads=5
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/http_error_api/wsgi.py
    WSGIScriptReloading On
    <Directory /var/www/http_error_api>
        WSGIProcessGroup application
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

**/etc/httpd/conf.d/mniek.ru.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ServerAdmin n-i-k-i-t@yandex.ru
 ServerName mniek.ru
 ServerAlias www.mniek.ru
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mniek.ru
 <Directory /var/www/mniek.ru>
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog /var/www/mniek.ru/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/mniek.ru/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerAdmin n-i-k-i-t@yandex.ru
 ServerName mniek.ru
 ServerAlias www.mniek.ru
 DocumentRoot /var/www/mniek.ru
 <Directory /var/www/mniek.ru>
 Options FollowSymLinks
 AllowOverride All
 Require all granted
 </Directory>
 ErrorLog /var/www/mniek.ru/logs/error.log
 CustomLog /var/www/mniek.ru/logs/access.log common
</VirtualHost>
```

And my **/var/www/http_error_api/wsgi.py** file:

```
from sys import path


path.insert(0, '/var/www/http_error_api')
from main import app as application
```

Apache logs:

```
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 0.0.26.144. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sun Jul 19 07:50:35.700799 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 65294] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 19 07:50:35.725938 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 65294] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 19 07:50:35.725986 2020] [core:notice] [pid 65294] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 19 07:55:41.639120 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 65294] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Jul 19 07:55:42.784997 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 65403] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 0.0.26.144. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sun Jul 19 07:55:42.838510 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 65403] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 19 07:55:42.868170 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 65403] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 19 07:55:42.868215 2020] [core:notice] [pid 65403] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
[Sun Jul 19 08:06:12.281355 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 65403] AH00170: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Sun Jul 19 08:06:13.880590 2020] [suexec:notice] [pid 65576] AH01232: suEXEC mechanism enabled (wrapper: /usr/sbin/suexec)
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 0.0.26.144. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
[Sun Jul 19 08:06:13.935885 2020] [lbmethod_heartbeat:notice] [pid 65576] AH02282: No slotmem from mod_heartmonitor
[Sun Jul 19 08:06:13.973518 2020] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 65576] AH00163: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS) OpenSSL/1.0.2k-fips PHP/5.4.16 mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.5 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Jul 19 08:06:13.973573 2020] [core:notice] [pid 65576] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/httpd -D FOREGROUND'
```

The problem is: when I open `mniek.ru`, I'm getting to my website. Also, when I go to `httpme.tk`, I'm also getting to my website, not to my flask application. What's wrong?

Comment: I am in same boat. Did you find solution?